# Writing Clang AST Matchers

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

Is it possible to use the bind string on one expression in the other like the following code:

```
expr(declRefExpr().bind("id"), hasDesendent(declRefExpr(has("id")));
```

Basically to use bind id string of one node to find the other node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using ***equalsBoundNode***

Usage:

```
expr(declRefExpr().bind("id"), hasDesendent(declRefExpr(equalsBoundNode("id")));
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to compare 2 nodes is to bind in different `id string`s and then compare them in the callback method.

This is explained in this [tutorial](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html).

In the above link you can find the following code:

```
const VarDecl *IncVar = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("incVarName");
const VarDecl *CondVar = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("condVarName");
if (!areSameVariable(IncVar, CondVar))
    return;
```

This code aims to compare nodes that are bind in variables `incVarName` and `condVarName` in the call back function.